# What's the best way to provide a library to external developers in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, header, static-libraries

I am writing a program in C# (Visual Studio 2010) and I have a set of functions that I want to make available to other people in the form of a library. What I did was create a new project and set the project type to *Class Library*. I noticed that the output type is DLL.

I don't necessarily want to provide a runtime library that others can link to dynamically what I want is to provide a set of functions that others can compile their code to. (I believe in C++ this would be a .lib file.)

In C# are all libraries DLLs?

Also, what if I only want to provide (as far as source code) the function definitions but not the implementation? In C++ you would give only the .h file but what do you give them in C#?

Comment: First thing I would recommend doing is forgetting C++. C++ and C# are completely different words and most techniques don't carry over between them.

Comment: I am very happy to forget about C++. :)

Answer (score 2):

DLL is what you would give in C#.

If you want to hide the implementation details then you can mark your classes as `internal`. But this would as long as the code that is using your library does not need to either reference your classes or create an instance of your classes. IF one of these is required, then there is no escaping from exposing your class implementation.

Comment: There are types in my library that external users would most certainly need to know about.

Comment: Then you can mark those types as public and happily hide the others using `internal` access modifier.

Comment: So lets say I have a class A that extends class B. The outside world needs only to know about class A and it's functions (some of which are inherited from B). Could I then mark B as internal or does the entire class heirarchy have to be public?

Comment: You cannot mark derived class as `public` and base class as `internal`. When an instance of derived class is created, an instance of base class also needs to be created, and if base class is `internal` this mechanism would not work. So compiler would not let you make a base class `internal` and derived class `public`

Comment: Ok got it! What I am providing is really quit simple.. I have an abstract class that other people need to extend in order to develop a plugin for my application. What I did was put this abstract class and it's implementation (the .CPP file) in a seperate C# _class library_ project. I will then distribute only these files to whomever wants to develop a plugin. As I stated in my comment to Chris below I might as well just give them the source code only and let them compile it.

Comment: A C# source file is a text file with the extension ".cs" (not ".CPP", that's C++). A C# class library may consist of serveral source files and is compiled into a single DLL file.

Answer (score 0):

As Suhas said, the DLL is what you want to distribute.

Yes, "libraries" are DLLs.  Technically they are called "assemblies" now.

Pretty much the only way I can think to do this for C# would be to have 2 assemblies.  The first containing only an `Interface` definition whereas the second contains the actual classes that implement the interface.  You could ship the first but not the second library.  If going that route, I would also provide a mocked class that implements the interface for simple testing.

This would involve dynamically loading the correct assembly at runtime; which is entirely feasible.  Usually through a config setting.

Going beyond that if the purpose in not providing the implementation is that you are worried about them decompiling the code, then you might look into some obfuscation tools.  Not 100% effective, but it certainly dissuades a lot of junior type devs.

Comment: I just though of something... if I have to give them the .DLL and the source file why not just give them the source and let them compile it? :)

Comment: That's certainly an option.  Open source projects tend to provide both a compiled assembly as well as the source.  This helps to get around issues where the build targets are different (x86 vs x64) or where they want to move up to a newer framework version (4.5 vs 2.0).  Also some dev's just like having the option of looking through the source in case there is a bug.

Comment: @ChrisLively I'm not sure how not distributing the assembly containing the implementation can work?

Comment: Would whomever is using my project just add a reference (of my stuff) to their project? Do references contain source and compile code?

Comment: Let me be a bit more specific... how would I _package_ up my deliverables? Just give them all the .cpp files and a .dll? Then would they have to create a new project and add those files to their project or would they just add a reference to my .dll? If they add a reference to the .dll where does the source code get added?

Comment: @JanTacci: If you are distributing source, then you send the entire project to them. (not your solution, but the Class Library project).  Then they would add a project reference to their existing (or new) solution which would cause it to recompile each time.

Comment: @Suhas: If the other developers project is supposed to be sent back to the OP for deployment, then the OP would change the config of the app to point to the correct assembly.  However, if the other developers project is supposed to be deployable by them and usable within intervention by the OP, then it couldn't work.  The OP would have to give them the full dll (or source).